# Short story about police monitoring people's emotional levels

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find an old science fiction short story in which the police monitor people's emotional levels. The climax of the story is a scene where the police prevent something fairly horrific, possibly a child murder, as a result of the police monitoring a person whose emotional level over the course of a day(?) gradually climbs to some extraordinary level.

Answer (score 3):

The sounds a lot like "The Circuit Riders" by R. C. FitzPatrick from the April 1962 *Analog*.  It fits every fact you provide in the question.

You can read the story on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/24543/24543-h/24543-h.htm)